# How does one properly set an onclicklistener within another class?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity which does all the setup process, i.e. creating the initial view and the OnClickListener, which then at some point creates an object passing the activity and OnClickListener as parameters. The object then does it's own setup, changing to view and setting TableRows with the OnClickListener. I run into the issue that when ever I click on one of the Rows, it seems OnClick(View v) is not called. The code seems solid but I'm either missing something or my implementation simply wont work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   private Object mObject;
   private TextView textView;

    private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.someId:
              mObject = new Object(MyActivity.this, mListener);
              break;
           case R.id.table_row:
              doSomething();
              break;
           }
       }
    }

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.someId);
    textView.setOnClickListener(mListener);
}

public class Object {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private OnClickListener mListener;
    private TableRow tableRow;
    public Object(Activity a, OnClickListener o) {
       mActivity = a;
       mListener = o;
       mActivity.setContentView(R.layout.layout);
       tableRow = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.table_row);
       tableRow.setOnClickListener(mListener)
    }
}
```

Edited code as suggested:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
   private Object mObject;
   private TextView textView;

    @override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.someId:
           mObject = new Object(MyActivity.this, mListener);
           break;
        case R.id.table_row:
           doSomething();
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

I omitted the Object class because with the above code onClick is not called without setting the OnClickListener with view.setOnClickListener(this); This also does not allow me to pass the Listener itself as a parameter, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

at first glance, it appears that you aren't attaching that listener to anything in the first place... What element gets to call your listener the first time around?  Your Object gets created when someone calls your Listener, but no one's calling it :)

Btw, you can implement onClickListener at the start of your Activity class creation, in which case, everything becomes clickable and you can then just listen for the id of what got clicked and react accordingly (rather than adding listeners, one at a time, to everything on the screen)... obviously this approach makes more sense when you have a bunch of clickable items (like a Battleship grid), rather than just a couple of buttons.

EDIT with example

```
public class MyGame extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
  //... onCreate and all that jazz

  //.. here you capture anything and everything getting clicked
  public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
         case R.id.myClickableObj1:
            //react to obj1 being clicked
         break;
         case R.id.myClickableObj2:
              //etc. etc.
         break;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I did omit adding code to clarify that I do some action, in this case touch a View, which would have the id "someID." I will edit, but I did not know that implementing OnClickListener would globally make everything clickable. If that's the case I can avoid this issue all together.

Comment: In hopes to clarify your answer, if I implement, do I need to set Listeners at all or will everything simply be automagicly set to my Listener? Previously when I would implement OnClickListener I would still do textView.setOnClickListener(this); but I stopped implementing OnCLickListener so that I could pass a Listener as a parameter. Is .setOnclickListener(this) not needed?

Comment: I have tried doing as you said, I re-implemented OnClickListener at the creation of my Activity class, but without explicitly setting an onClickListener with setOnClickListener(this) I can not get it to work. Would it be much of a bother to provide some sample code to how you would implement and have everything globally clickable?

Comment: added example code above... haven't run it so, maybe typos, but will work (in principal)

Comment: I did, earlier, exactly what you posted but to no avail. If I do not explicitly set the onClickListener, as in, for example, view.setOnClickListener(this); I do not get a callback to onClick.